# Transfering Freecell stats from one computer to another

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My Windows 7 system died (boo hoo). I now have another Windows 7 system (YEAH!!!), but, I would like to transfer my FREECELL stats. (500 plus wins without a loss - thank you very much.) The system hard drive from the dead system is intact and I have added it to the new system as a secondary drive. The new system will not allow me to play the FREECELL while it resides as the 2nd drive, but I can, of course, play the new systems FREECELL. Can I transfer the stats? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

#### Can I transfer the stats?

In Windows 7 the freecell statistics are stored in `FreeCellSettings.xml`

The full path of the file is:

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft Games\FreeCell\FreeCellSettings.xml
```

You can copy this file to your new installation:

1. Run `freecell` on the new installation once to create the appropriate directories/files.
2. Make a note of the `FreeCellSettings.xml` file ownership/permissons settings
3. Copy `FreeCellSettings.xml` from the secondary drive to `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft Games\FreeCell\`
4. Fix up file ownership/permissions as needed using the settings from step 2.

Comment: Plus you can edit that file and change your score!

Comment: @Keltari True, but it's a little difficult to edit because the so-called FreeCellSettings.xml file is a binary file containing a couple of sub-files. There is a listing of file names at the beginning, then a PNG image, then an XML file in UTF-16 containing your stats.

Answer (score 0):

**OR** export the registry and import to the new computer
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Freecell